# Parse gps coordinates as a road on an offline map (opposite of a gps)

Tags: python, gps, openstreetmap, offline

I'm trying to make an offline application in which I can draw my driven road in (near) real time on a map. I was thinking about using [open street map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), but if someone knows a much better solution, I'll take a look at it for sure.

So what I want to do, is when I drive with my car, I have a GPS module on top of it with a raspberry pi. On the raspberry pi, there is a screen connected to it on what I want to display the map. The application that runs on it is an **offline** html site with Python (running on [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/)). I want that the map is offline and as accurate as possible. And when I'm driving, it needs to de the opposite thing of a GPS. Instead of saying where to go, it needs to record where you are going.

Later, I want to be able to export the recorded route, but if I get the route drawn on the map **offline** I would be really happy already. So is there someone who can help me with this? Or already have made something like this?

Comment: This question is very broad, probably beyond the scope of SO. You should give this a go yourself, and come back to ask for help if you encounter problems.

Comment: I already tried **ALOT** and never was be able to fix this. I thought, let me throw this on SO and see if someone encounter this problem too. And maybe someone is able of helping me (and others)

Comment: Take a look at [what topics you can ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - I think your question is probably too broad to be answerable. Is there any particular reason why you want to have it attached to a screen in your car, or could you just get a GPS logger and process the data at home?

Comment: So what you need is a GPS logger. Additionally you want to draw the track that has been logged, e.g. a GPX file. The logging part is simple to implement. The drawing part can be done with Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: So I'm making my own version of a [tripmaster](http://tripmaster.be/index.php?route=product/category&path=64), but with alot more new features. I want to be able to see the road I've driven in real time, but the screen also gives me the current speed, the current driven distance, etc... So yes, I need the screen and real-time "parsing" of the data. I can't precess the data at home. That's the main goal of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

I do this in a slightly different form my web site for this is as  http://sy-edm.com/tt/

You need

to parse the GPS CoOrdinates from your GPS Device
   Store in a Database 
   Using open-Street-Maps create an overlay, where you select your coords from your database and display them.

I used an I-Phone with a GPS App that had the ability to post data to a Web-Url.